# Reminders in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, reminders

I want to implement a scheduled reminder in a Food/Eating application created in Xamarin Forms (android & ios), that will be displayed at a precise hour on my phone.

Also I want, if it's possible (but I think somehow should be done...), the reminders to be displayed even if the application is not opened. I know that I have some applications installed on my phone, and even if they are closed, the reminders are still displayed.

Could you please help with this topic? I have done some research on the internet but I couldn't found anything that works...

Thank you in advance!
Regards!

Comment: You can use [local-notifications-in-ios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/deprecated/local-notifications-in-ios) to send reminds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) in android, please refer to [alarm-manager-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example).